# How do i select a specific part of an array or Vector when MouseEvent clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Hi i am new to AS3 just couple of months into OOP i am not sure how do i select a specific part of an array or Vector when MouseEvent clicked.

So i parsed a list of Vector into this class called SearchVectorTest , and they are put into containers, i am trying to select the specific part of the Vector(which is text) when a specific container(box)that contain that part of the text is clicked. So that i can parse it to the next class file for further use.

At the moment i only have some idea about how to get the index of the part clicked which is below but it doesnt work.

```
var clickedpart:listings = Holder.target as Listing8;
    var listIndex:uint = listings.indexOf(clickedpart);
    trace("You clicked the part at index " + listIndex);
```

and i just tried this `trace( bf.text+bf1.text+ bf2.text+bf3.text);`
and it trace the last 4 text correctly, but not the one that i clicked.

This is the fullset of the SearchVectorTest

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var listings:Vector.<Listing8>;
         public var _contentHolder: Sprite;
        public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {




                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {


                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);

        }



            var james:int = test ? test.length : 0;

 listings = new Vector.<Listing8>(james, true);
            var currentY:int = 100;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8();

                Bolder.x=20;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;



                    // Pulling the textfields content out from the current bookVO

                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.2
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);
                Bolder.properties = test[k].nobed;
                Bolder.properties = test[k].zip;

                    // position the object based on the accumulating variable.
                Bolder.y = currentY;


                addChild(Bolder);
                 Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
            Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
            Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
            Bolder.buttonMode = true; 

                 listings[k] = Bolder;
                currentY += Bolder.height + 10;
            }
            if( listings.length > 0 )
             {
                 _contentHolder = new Sprite();


    addChild(_contentHolder);






    for (var j:int = 0; j < listings.length; j++) {
         _contentHolder.addChild(listings[j]);



    }






       _contentHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
   }

        function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{

   var clickedpart:Listing8 = Bolder.target as Listing8;
   var listIndex:uint = listings.indexOf(clickedpart);
   trace( bf.text+bf1.text+ bf2.text+bf3.text);







            while(_contentHolder.numChildren > 0)
           {
_contentHolder.removeChildAt(0);

       }

  while(GLOBALS.resultholder.numChildren > 0)
{
   GLOBALS.resultholder.removeChildren();
}


var s5:Listingdetail= new Listingdetail ();
     addChild(s5);


}


        }


    }

}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your code has syntax issues (`clickedpart:listings`) and is not indented. If you isolate the problem more and fix those issues, it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Ok, will do, thanks, i am working on it and i managed to get it to trace the last 4 part of the text from the Vector, now trying to figure out how to select the part that is clicked.

Comment: I tried for another 2 hrs or so. The only thing i managed to do is trace the last 4 part of the text or use indexOf to display how many boxes were there. But i wasnt able to trace the index of the box clicked or trace the text from the box clicked. Wondering if you can give me some clue on either how to get the index of the box(_contentHolder) clicked? So then i can keep trying on it, to get to displaying the selected text? Because at the moment the indexOf i use doesnt show the index but just the amount of _contentHolder

Comment: Just managed to do it, just now

Answer (score 0):

```
function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{


    var searchString = listings;
            var index:Number;
            index = searchString.indexOf(e.target);
    trace(test[index].nobed+test[index].zip+test[index].Location+test[index].price);
}
```